# How to sort a list according to numeric strings

Tags: c#, list, linq

My list holds objects that have 2 string fields:

```
        public class worker
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Hours{ get; set; }
        }

         List<worker> work= new List<worker>();
            work.Add(new worker{"Ron","2"});
            work.Add(new worker{"Alex","202" });
            work.Add(new worker{"Brad","11"});
            work.Add(new worker{"Micky","33"});
            work.Add(new worker{"Anna","22"});
```

I need this output after sorting: `Alex,Micky,Anna,Brad,Ron`
clarify - hours are count of hours.
How do I do that?

Comment: Should not hours be an int?

Comment: @Magnus yes it should but unfortunately I get it as a string..

Comment: Try `work.OrderBy(w => int.Parse(x.Hours))`. If you have lots of items this will be rather inefficient though. In order to improve performance, consider converting all `worker` objects into types of the same shape but with `int Hours`.

Comment: `work.Sort((w1, w2) => int.Parse(w1.Hours).CompareTo(int.Parse(w2.Hours)));` You can also try `CompareTo` as it may provide a little performance improvement compared to creating a new sorted list using OrderBy in some scenarios.

Comment: Would you know how to sort the data that way if `Hours` was type `int`? Do you know how to convert a `string` to an `int`? If the answers are both "yes", why do you need to ask this question at all? If either answer is "no", why aren't you researching how do those things? You should be able to show us that you have at least got that far and then explain what the specific issue is.

Comment: There's a "natural sort" function in Windows that you can call via P/Invoke to compare numeric strings - whether this would be faster than just calling `int.Parse()` is something you would have to determine by benchmarking. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp

Comment: @AqibChattha, I believe that your suggestion will actually be less efficient. Your suggestion requires both `string` values to be converted every time two items are compared. Using `OrderBy` will result in each `string` value being converted once, regardless of the number of comparisons. Your method will always require more conversions. Of course, if sorting in place is required then you might have no choice.

Comment: @MatthewWatson, I could be wrong but I find it hard to imagine that that would be more efficient. That method is useful when you have `strings` that all contain the same text and different digits but for just digits I'd be shocked if it was faster than an option specifically designed for just digits.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes sir, I know that it performs more conversions. But considering large lists then creating a new ordered sequence using `OrderBy` would be more of a burden than in-place sorting, it depends on the situation I guess :)

Comment: Oh, and If the list is small then I would recommend creating a new list with Hours as int, and storing them would be more efficient than temporarily converting them during sorting. It would be less troublesome with later calculations :>

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I tried a benchmark and just using `int.Parse()` is around 3 times faster than using the Windows API (at least on my PC)

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that all the hours are numbers, you must use the method

```
var _List = string.Join("," ,
work.OrderByDescending(d => int.Parse(d.Hours)
).Select(d => d.Name).ToArray());
```

Otherwise, you have to create a field in the class or separate class as follows

```
var _Lists = string.Join(",", 
work.OrderByDescending(d => ConvertData.ConvertIntTostring(d.Hours)
).Select(d => d.Name).ToArray());
```

ConvertData

```
public static class ConvertData
{
    public static int ConvertIntTostring(string number)
    {
        int result = 0;
        int.TryParse(number, out result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ordering can be done like this if every string is a number for sure.

```
 var orderedWorkers = work.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Hours));
```

If you have strings which are not a number i would create a separate property in the worker class which makes sure to return always a valid number.

```
    public class worker
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Hours{ get; set; }
        public int HoursAsInt
        {
            get
            {
                int.TryParse(Hours, out int hoursAsInt);
                return hoursAsInt;
            }
        }
    }
```